# How to pass connection parameter "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" when using pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I only have readonly access to a SQL Server db. How do I pass connection parameter "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" when using pymssql to connect to the database? If pymssql doesn't support it, is there any other python library that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pymssql is dependent on FreeTDS 
You really need to address the connection parameters to your MS-SQL server used by FreeTDS

Because ApplicationIntent is listed in the freetds [user guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm) as an option you should be able to use it.

Comment: The link is not working anymore. Here is the [new one](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/OdbcConnAttr.html).

Comment: I came to this thread trying to do same as OP and the answer is little confusing for me. Are we saying we CAN set `ApplicationIntent='ReadOnly'` using `pymssql`? If yes then how? I tried using `conn=pymssql.connect('db_host_nm','db_usr_nm','db_pwd','db_nm',charset='UTF-8',port=1433,ApplicationIntent='ReadOnly')` but keep getting error `TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ApplicationIntent'` Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to configure readonly connection intent with pymssql seems to be to configure freetds on which it's based, but it did not work out for me. I've had to use pyodbc instead of pymssql

```
from pyodbc import connect
conn = connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + host + ';PORT=' + port + ';DATABASE='
    + database + ';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + password + ';ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly')
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is working fine! The only requirement is that the ODBC driver for MSSQL is installed on the system. For example on my Windows 10 machine I installed [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567).

Answer (score 0):

pyodbc has a readonly parameter.  For example:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=Server, database=Database,
                  trusted_connection='yes', user='', password='', readonly = True)
```

Comment: Any reason why this was marked as not useful? Works fine for me without any issues?

Comment: Probably because the question is asking about pymssql, not pyodbc.